# If I click the button in dialog model, after how can I run page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to continue deletion upon modal button click. I thought if I run page load function, I can continue deletion.

What do you think about this .How can I do that? Also, I have and update panel, Can I use the update panel for this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          title: 'Basic Dialog',
          buttons: {
              Delete:  function () {
                  deleteRecord(); 
                  $(this).dialog('close');  
              },
              Close: function () {
                  $(this).dialog('close');
              }
          }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not sure I understood what are you trying to do? Do you want to call the deleteRecord() on page load or when the user clicks 'delete' button?

Comment: @man_luck I did that. I want to load page after deletion,  for can be deletion again

Comment: here is a similar one where you can load the page in ajaxStop() callback, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881089/reload-the-page-after-ajax-success

Comment: I didn't find. Thank you @man_luck