# Jquery refresh the page after success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How do I refresh the page after ajax call success. The page doesn't refresh even thought I have put `window.location.reload(true)`. It only displays the echo message but doesn't refresh it

```
$("#update-btn").click(function() {
    var token = document.getElementById('tokenAmount').value;; //Place the token here
    var master = currentUserID;
    var lastUser = lastNode.info.id;
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "update.php", 
        data : {'master': master,
            'token' : token,
            'user_id': lastUser 
        },
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    }); 
});
```

## update.php

```
$master=$_POST['master'];
$user = $_POST['user_id'];
$token = $_POST['token'];

if(condition)
{
    $result = $MySQLi_CON->query($secondToken);
    if($result == false)
        $response['msg'] = "Not Enough";
    else
    {    
        $response['msg'] = "Successful";
    }
}

else
{
    $response['msg'] = "Not enough";
}
echo json_encode($response['msg']);
```

Comment: use a flag session for this status

Comment: I see a `}` in more at the line 15 of 'update.php'. Check it please

Comment: alert(data); what data are you getting in alert?

Comment: echo message alert

Comment: I mean it alerts 'Successful' or 'Not enough' ?

Comment: Why are you using AJAX if you're going to reload the page anyway? The usual purpose of AJAX is so you can make changes without reloading.

Comment: it says successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next statement wont execute unless you click Ok on alert().
So use console.log(data) instead.

```
success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                window.location.href=window.location.href;
            }
```

Comment: can you put your data output in console.log(data) instead of alert();

Comment: it says successful but not refreshing either

Comment: Yes it should. The issue was with alert()  box.

Answer (score 1):

`.ajaxStop()` callback executes when all AJAX call completed. This is a best place to put your handler.

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    window.location.reload();
});
```

The source is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7881255/5930557)

Comment: where should i query that?

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code :-

```
location.reload();
```

**Edited :-**

```
success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
            location.reload();
        }
```

**Other ways :-**

```
location.reload()
history.go(0)
location.href = location.href
location.href = location.pathname
location.replace(location.pathname)
location.reload(false)
```

Please have a look on below link :- There are 534 other ways to reload the page with JavaScript :-

http://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html

Comment: all above doesn't work. It doesn't seem to reload the page

Comment: There's no difference between `location.reload` and `window.location.reload`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location.reload(true);
```

Comment: try this   window.location.href=window.location.href;

Comment: It doesn't seem to reload the page

Comment: Generally "try this" answers aren't helpful at all. Try to explain why this would improve OPs code or be the solution to why he had his problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

**In your ajax success callback do this:**

```
success: function(response){
                setTimeout(function(){
                   location.reload()
                }, 5000);
    }
```

> As you want to reload the page after 5 seconds, then you need to have
>   a timeout as suggested in the answer.

Comment: In your ajax success callback do this:


 success: function(response){
       setTimeout(function(){
          location.reload()
          }, 5000);
    }

As you want to reload the page after 5 seconds, then you need to have a timeout as suggested in the answer.

Comment: Edit it into the post please