# if statement not working jquery

Tags: php, jquery

This should be simple, but doesn't work

Essentially I want to get a return result and reload my page if the answer is 'yes'

Here is the 
**timer.php**

```
<?php
    $filename = 'timer.tmr';

    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        unlink($filename);
        echo 'yes';
    } else {
        echo 'no';
    }
?>
```

and here is the script in my main file

```
var myVar = setInterval(function () {myTimer()}, 5000);
function myTimer() {
     sendto =  "timer.php";
     $.get(sendto, function(data, status) {
         if (data === 'yes') {
            location.reload();
         }
     });
}
```

Basically in the **timer.php**

If the file exists I delete it and return a 'yes'

But the `jquery` doesn't do the reload function, if I check the data with an alert(data), it returns a 'yes' So I just don't understand the problem.

Comment: try window.location.reload();

Comment: How do you know it's not reloading?  Try location.reload(true) to force a hard reload.

Comment: Can you try with `if (data == 'yes')`? because there might be an issue with `'yes'`.

Comment: what happens when you use `=='yes'` instead of `==='yes`

Comment: If you are getting into the `if` condition, then you should try `window.location.href = window.location.href;` instead of `location.reload();`

Comment: and If you're not getting into the `if` condition, change condition with `if ($.trim(data) === "yes") `

Comment: Ahhh finally success, thank you that did it, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting into the `if` condition, then you should try `window.location.href = window.location.href;` instead of `location.reload();`

and If you're not getting into the `if` condition, change condition with `if ($.trim(data) === "yes")`

---

thanks to Shaunak Shukla (again thank you)

here is the final solution

```
     var myVar = setInterval(function () {myTimer()}, 10000);
     function myTimer() {
     sendto =  "timer.php";
     $.get(sendto, function(data, status) {
     if ($.trim(data) === "yes"){
       location.reload();
       }
      });

       }
```

it needed the trim(data) must have had something in it..

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode in the echos and improve your checking:

```
<?php
$filename = 'timer.tmr';

if (file_exists($filename)) {

    unlink($filename);
    if (!file_exists($filename))
       echo json_encode('yes');
    else
       echo json_encode('no');
} else {

    echo json_encode('no');
}

?>
```

And change the reload to a more direct scope:

```
 var myVar = setInterval(function () {myTimer()}, 5000);
 function myTimer() {

 sendto =  "timer.php";
 $.get(sendto, function(data, status) {
   if (data === 'yes'){
    window.location.reload();
  }
  });

  }
```

Comment: He mentioned that `alert(data)` does return 'yes'. Which means, its working fine and doesn't need json. Hmm?

Comment: Yeah, but is better always send a json content when working with ajax.

Comment: I made the changes and it still didn't work... driving me bonkers

Comment: Put data == 'yes' just to test. And put console.log to us, please

Comment: I know the reload isn't working because my page isn't getting refreshed..

Comment: @Karter what happens when you use `=='yes'` instead of `==='yes` ?

Comment: I had already tried that, but just to make sure, I changed it and still no change

Comment: Try .done(function() {
    window.location.reload();
  })

Comment: it appears that it is not getting past the if statement

Comment: @ShaunakShukla I know, i'm just trying other approach to see if the callbacks are working.

Karte, As I thought. Put typeof data here plz

Comment: @ShaunakShukla It's true... thanks man, sry, i didn't pay attention

Answer (score 0):

Let complete ajax request then try to reload :

```
setTimeout(function(){// wait for 5 secs(2)
        location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
}, 5000);
```

Comment: don't quite understand what you want me to do here

Comment: @Karter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881089/reload-the-page-after-ajax-success

Answer (score 0):

I would Suggest, please check the Type casting (data type). I find, you have used === , it will check string to string or int to int.

Comment: it is returning a string

Comment: Then please use trim function on data that return from ajax